# http request partial response

Tags: php, html, xmlhttprequest

I'm not an expert on http request so this question might be trivial for some. I'm sending a request to a php script which takes a lot of time to process a file and return a response. Is there a way to send a response before this script finishes its task to let the user know about the process status? Since this task can take up to several minutes I'd like to notify the user when key parts of the process are finished.

Note: I cannot break this request into several others

I might not have the correct approach here if so do you have other ideas how this could be handled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically yes, but it would require you to have fine grained control of the http-stack, which you may or may not have in a typical php setup. I would suggest you look into other solutions (E.g. Make request to start the task - then poll to get an update on the progress)

Answer (score 0):

http://www.redips.net/javascript/ajax-progress-bar/

here's a great article that goes over creating ajax a progress bar to use with php.

let me know if it doesn't make sense!

Comment: I'm not looking for a progress bar.

Comment: the only thing i can think of then would be to have the php script store the session id and the progress value (however you'd like to compute it) in a db that is checked with ajax asynchronously.

these could be associative statuses rather than numerically.  e.g., status='doing first task'...status='first task complete, starting second task'...etc

but the idea remains to have the second ajax call to check what the script is updating as it goes through its processes

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way for long proccessing requests is cron jobs. You can send request which will create 'task' and catch the task by cron job. Cron job can change task status while working and you can check task status via interval requests. I can't imagine another way to inform users about request proccessing. As soon as you response your headers are sent and PHP stops.

EDIT: it should be noted that Cron jobs are only available on Linux servers.  windows servers would require access to the task scheduler, which most web hosts will not allow.